# How do I solve 'UserWarning: DataFrame columns are not unique, some columns will be omitted'?

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, dictionary

i have a dataframe of 2 columns. i tried converting it into a dictionary using df2.set_index('pay').T.to_dict('list').

As there are duplicated keys, some columns were omitted. Is there any way to resolve this issue or an alternative method?

| pay | score |
| --- | --- |
| 500 | 1 |
| 700 | 4 |
| 1000 | 5 |
| 700 | 3 |

I would like to achieve this dictionary.

{'0': [500, 1], '1': [700, 4], '2': [1000, 5], '3' [700, 3]}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC use:

```
d = df2.T.to_dict('list')
print (d)
{0: [500, 1], 1: [700, 4], 2: [1000, 5], 3: [700, 3]}
```